# Can we use copy command to load data into redshift table from S3 using access key and secret key (Without with IAM Role)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I have a requirement where I need to load data into Redshift table from S3. Files present in the S3 are in Parquet format. I don't have an IAM policy but have an S3 Access Key and Secret Key.

Things to note: Redshift and S3 are in two different AWS accounts however these accounts are in the same region.

What I have tried:

```
copy abc from 's3://us-publish-prod/customer/r_cust_geo_funcl_terr_addr_elig/' 
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=XXXXXXXXX;aws_secret_access_key=XXXXXXXXXXX'
FORMAT AS PARQUET;

Error: Invalid operation: COPY from this file format only accepts IAM_ROLE credentials
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

According to [COPY from columnar data formats - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-usage_notes-copy-from-columnar.html), it seems that loading data from Parquet format requires use of an IAM Role rather than IAM credentials:

> `COPY` command credentials must be supplied using an AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) role as an argument for the `IAM_ROLE` parameter or the `CREDENTIALS` parameter.

This would mean using either of:

```
CREDENTIALS 'aws_iam_role=arn:aws:iam::<aws-account-id>:role/<role-name>'
IAM_ROLE 'arn:aws:iam::<aws-account-id>:role/<role-name'
```

Thus, **you need to use an IAM Role**, even if the files were stored in your own AWS account.

You will therefore need to:

- Ask your admins to **create an IAM Role in the account with Amazon Redshift** with permissions to use `GetObject` and `ListBucket` on the S3 bucket that contains the source data (in the other account)
- Ask the admins of the 'other' account to **add the IAM Role to the bucket policy** where the files are being stored, so that the IAM Role has `GetObject` and `ListBucket` permissions (most likely identical to what they have granted to your IAM User)
- Authorize the Redshift cluster to use the IAM Role
- Modify your `COPY` command to use the IAM Role instead of credentials

See: [Authorizing Amazon Redshift to access other AWS services on your behalf](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/authorizing-redshift-service.html)